# FlipClock.js works fine on Chrome but not counting on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, flipclock

I've trouble with [FlipClock.js](http://flipclockjs.com/). Below I present code samples from my site:

HTML part:

```
 <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-2"></div>
     <div class="col-md-8 text-center">
          <div id="buttons">
               <div class="my-clock"></div>
          </div>
     </div>
 <div>
```

and javascript part:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var clock;

        $(document).ready(function() {

            // Grab the current date
            var currentDate = new Date();

            // Set some date in the past. In this case, it's always been since Jan 1
            var pastDate  = new Date("2016-02-20 10:00:00");

            // Calculate the difference in seconds between the future and current date
            var diff = pastDate.getTime() / 1000 - currentDate.getTime() / 1000;

            // Instantiate a coutdown FlipClock
            clock = $('.my-clock').FlipClock(diff, {
                clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
                countdown: true
            });

        });
    </script>
```

And here screens from Chrome:

[image]

and Firefox:

[image]

In Firefox the counter doesn't work at all. What can I do wrong?

Comment: firefox doesn't like the milliseconds as a STRING in new Date - get rid of the quotes ... or make it `new Date(+"{{ miliseconds }}")`

Comment: firefox doesn't like that date format in new Date ...

Comment: `var pastDate  = new Date("2016-02-20T10:00:00");` will work (note the 'T') - be careful of timezones though

Comment: Someone needs to post as an answer so future visitors can clearly see the solution

Comment: I do that tomorrow its my own home side project.